# No module named 'urllib3.packages.six.moves'

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib3, six

I'm trying to use the groupme API with GroupyAPI, but I'm having some issues with urllib3.

```
import urllib3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\smlac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\smlac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\smlac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.packages.six.moves'
```

I have tried this on both my laptop and PC, for some reason it works on my PC, but I need to use it on my laptop as well.  I have uninstalled urllib and reinstalled it, I have verified the versions match with what I'm using on my PC and they all match. I made sure that python is in my environmental variables path. I just don't understand why it only works on my PC.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Python versions are the same too?

Comment: PC is python 3.10.0. Laptop is the latest version. I think 3.12

Comment: Searching "urllib3.packages.six.moves" on Google I see other similar errors but could not find the reason. I would try to update the versions of urllib3 and six packages. Version 1.26.5 of urllib3 changes the version of six to 1.16.0 https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/1.26.6/